# Building Java projects with circular imports in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, circular-dependency

I have a legacy Java (not my native language) app that I'm trying to build in Eclipse Galileo.

As it's not my own, I can't speak to the quality of the design, but I am coming across a number of instances where I'll have something like this:

In a project called, say, "lib_a", I'll have a file containing this:

```
import com.acme.lib_b.onething;
```

Project "lib_b" on the other hand, will contain:

```
import com.acme.lib_a.anotherthing;
```

Of course, the problem is that one project can't be built because the errors prevent me from creating a .jar file that can be added as an external archive to the other project, and vice versa.

It seems to me that this must be a fairly common occurence in building Java applications.  Rewriting it from scratch is not an option here, so I'd like to know "what other folks do."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can link projects in eclipse, so you're essentially declaring one project as a dependency of another, just like declaring a jar.

Project:-> Properties -> click on the "projects" tab, click "add", and you'll have the option of any open project.Additionally eclipse tracks these so that when you open "A" linked project "B" opens.

Comment: The errors are a completely separate problem - you haven't mentioned what they are!

Comment: It will work sufficiently for loading imports. However, if your projects are really messed up, and they have conflicting imports and such things, you might be better off building a minimal jar by hand for inclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe if onething and anotherthing aren't core parts of each project (e.g., utility classes), then you could move one into the other project to make the references one-way, or create a common util.jar.

Otherwise I would merge the projects if they are interrelated to a great extent.

Comment: I like the common util idea.  It adds an extra step, but it would allow me to factor out problematical definitions so I can at least get one project built.  The common library might even be temporary until I can reintroduce those definitions back into their original classes.

Answer (score 2):

Basically a sign of poor design.  Possible solutions

- there are common parts in the 2 libs that should be refactored into a "common" library
- both libraries are really 2 halves of the same library and should be combined
- one library is relying on the "internals" of another library and some interfaces should be introduced to break this bad dependency

Answer (score 1):

I'd just merge them as a single project.

If you cant use A without B and you cant use B without A having separate JAR files doesn't seem very useful.